# is it possible to get disk usage per process using top and ps command?

Tags: linux, process

I am trying to find out if is possible to get disk usage using the above mentioned commands in terminal but no luck. Can anyone help? if there is not, then is there any other command that can I use to do the same thing as top/ ps but with disk usage?

Thank You

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by “disk usage”?  Do you mean I/O stats per process? What files they are using?

Comment: I use atop to get per process disk I/O usage stats, but it requires root access.

Comment: @jsbillings I am referring to actual disk space that the process requires, my concept maybe completely wrong as I am new to this. I was asked to use a command to show all the processes and cpu, memory and disk usage. I don't exactly if it is possible or not. If not, can you teach me why it is impossible?

Comment: Your problem is you probably misunderstood the question. The indicator of this is, is that there is no such thing as disk usage per process. Read it as 1) show all processes with their cpu and memory usage -which is a legit question-, 2) show disk usage, which is also a good one. In basic computer usage these are the questions to answer on any problem or task.

Answer (score 2):

There are two meanings for disk usage here.

Disk disk space usage is summarized by the `du` and `df` commands.
the `df` command summarizes total disk size, use, and free space by mounted partition.   The `du` command summarizes total disk use by directory and file.

Disk I/O bandwidth use over a time interval which can be displayed with tools like `iostat` and `atop`.

The `iostat` command shows total live disk activity on each disk.  By default, it shows averages since boot, but can also be given a time interval and show what happened during that interval.

The `atop` command will also show similar statistics to what iostat shows, but if run as root in **d**isk mode (press <kbd>d</kbd>), will show disk I/O utilization by process.

Note that disk space utilization by process doesn't make sense, because processes don't use disk space, files do.  What would disk space by process mean?  Do you mean size of the executable?  Size of the executable and shared libraries?  Size of the open files? None of these belong to a single process, but are shared between all processes that use those files.  Disk blocks read and written is available as a statistic, but has little or no relation to disk space used, as the same block could be read and written multiple times, and this statistic also includes I/O from swap and demand paging.